# ссылка на вверх и вниз страницы (точнее кнопка, иконка вверх и вниз) не отображается на мобильном сайте

Tags: адаптивная-верстка, мобильная-разработка

Всем добра!
Ссылка на вверх и вниз страницы (точнее кнопка, иконка вверх и вниз) не отображается на мобильном сайте. Причём на не мобильном сайте отображается.
Причём я обратил внимание, что те же кнопки встроены в браузер интернета на андроиде, и они тоже не отображаются.
Что можно сделать подскажите пожалуйста?!

Ссылка на сайт:

https://regmed-global.com/uzbekistan/uz_med_dev_docs.php

Я покопался и обнаружил, что если я уберу из style.css вот эти коды, то на мобильном нормально отображаются кнопки вверх и вниз, как и на обычном сайте:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .site-pusher,
  .site-container {
    height: 100%;
  }

  .site-container {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .site-pusher {
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  
  .site-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 66px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
 }
  }
```